# how to create a "https" secured REST API from a SOAP servies in java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, https

I am working on integrating a SOAP service provided by european VAT validation service VIES.
the SOAP service is hosted at following links
https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
I think both of them leads to pretty much same site with one being http and other https
**(please let me know if there is a difference)**.

so I integrated the wsdl into our spring boot application and it worked fine when I tried in in my local host which was http. but as soon as I hosted it in to our live server which is https it started giving error reply.

I searched for possible reasons why it isn't working and ended up with the conclusion that the SOAP services provided by VTES works only in http sites.**(let me know if I am wrong)**
but when I searched for more solutions I found more sites that provide https secured REST application that uses same SOAP service (https://vatlayer.com/) . We tried to reason with our client to purchase one of those since they only allow a limited number of free VAT validations, but they are not happy with that,
but it got me thinking since they can built a https secured REST API with this thing it means I can do that to. so I searched for a solution but couldn't find any, can anyone please give a insight into it about how it is done.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the link from the  web browser(client side) and if your live web application runs on HTTPS, then you should also call the SOAP service with HTTPS or otherwise the browser will see it as violating the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and will block your request.